# How can we prove mathematically that a body not at zero kelvin emits radiations of all wavelengths?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, temperature, thermal-radiation

Well, today our teacher was taking up the topic *Radiation* under the chapter *Properties of Matter*. And he said that all bodies with a temperature above zero kelvin emit EM waves with *all* wavelengths right from zero to infinity units. I just want to know how can we just say it like that, I mean ther must be some proof to this statement. I asked him then and there, but he just said that it was not in JEE syllabus. Please tag me if you are aware of any proof as such (**mathematical**, of course).

P.S. - I am an IIT JEE Advanced 2025 aspirant.

Comment: Mathematical proofs aren't what drive physics, physics is an empirical science by it's very nature, we model what we see with formulas and try to then use those formula to predict further behavior and test them against better experiments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The formula we use, [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law), matches experiments and *mathematically* predicts nonzero emission at all wavelengths. However, for a given temperature, the emission peaks at a particular wavelength and declines very rapidly for shorter wavelengths. You cannot practically detect thermal emission at a wavelength less than the peak wavelength divided by ~10.

Note that we cannot mathematically prove that this is the correct formula: experiments are necessary. We can derive it mathematically from certain assumptions, but then it depends on the unprovable veracity of those assumptions.